# cant update data using ionic and firebase on childe node structure

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I have problem for updating data with ionic firebase using this code,this code just make it a new data not rewrite the previous data  .
here is the code :

```
updateLaporan()
      {
        this.id =this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid;    
        this.db.object('/laporan/'+ this.id+ this.uid).set({
          porsiKarbohidrat : this.porsiKarbohidrat.value,
          porsiProteinHewani : this.porsiProteinHewani.value,
          porsiProteinNabati : this.porsiProteinNabati.value,
          porsiLemak : this.porsiLemak.value,

         })

         this.alert("Sukses")
      }
```

this is the capture of my database:
[firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoXjA.png)
this is what will be happen if i use that code
[This is what will be happen if i use the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZiK2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `/` in between your id's to go deeper

```
this.db.object('/laporan/'+ this.id+'/'+ this.uid).update()
```

use `.update` instead `.set` or everything under current node will be rewrite.